# how to fix error featuretools package install python

Tags: featuretools

I get this error when installing featuretools... why?

> "NewConnectionError<' failed to establish  a new connection:
>   [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',>

Comment: This likely isn't a featuretools issue. Are you using pip to install?

Comment: yes, I am trying

Comment: this is likely an issue with pip or your internet connection. It does not seem related to Featuretools.